# beamer block inside an itemize environment with overlays

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays, rendering

I have a frame like this, there is a block inside the itemize environment, and there is an overlay :

```
\begin{frame}   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \frametitle{Comparing two Gaussian means: equality}

\begin{itemize}

\item<1-> Assume for instance that each measurement is $\approx 1000$ 

\item<1-> Would you mind if $\mu_1=1000$ and $\mu_2=1000.1$ ?

\item<1->[] 
\begin{alertblock}{Significant difference does not mean important difference}
  "The mean of the Gaussian distribution is well estimated whenever $n \geq 30$ 
  "Significant difference" is a shortcut for \emph{significantly different from $0$}. 
  The presence of a significant difference shows that there is a strong evidence that 
  $\boxed{\mu_1 \neq \mu_2}$ 
\end{alertblock}

\vspace{-13pt}
\item<1->[] 
\begin{columns}[T]
\column{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Whether $\mu_1=\mu_2$ or  $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$  is \emph{not} the question of interest
\item<2-> xx
\end{itemize}
\column{.5\linewidth}
\only<2->{\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
}
\end{columns}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

You can see [the rendering here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsh380xn59tlhiv/significant_difference_anim.pdf). The problem is that the two slides are not well superposed, and I have done many unsuccessful attempts to solve that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly the purpose of the `overlay` area environment; in my example I used a dummy-image at the bottom:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frametitle{Comparing two Gaussian means: equality}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Assume for instance that each measurement is $\approx 1000$ 
\item<1-> Would you mind if $\mu_1=1000$ and $\mu_2=1000.1$ ?
\item<1->[] 
\begin{alertblock}{Significant difference does not mean important difference}
  "The mean of the Gaussian distribution is well estimated whenever $n \geq 30$ 
  "Significant difference" is a shortcut for \emph{significantly different from $0$}. 
  The presence of a significant difference shows that there is a strong evidence that 
  $\boxed{\mu_1 \neq \mu_2}$ 
\end{alertblock}
\vspace{-13pt}
\item<1->[] 
\begin{columns}[T]
\column{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Whether $\mu_1=\mu_2$ or  $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$  is \emph{not} the question of interest
\item<2-> xx
\end{itemize}
\column{.5\linewidth}
\only<2->{\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
}
\end{columns}
\end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! By the way, how have you (generated and) included this animated output here ?

Comment: Ooopppss... in case there are some reader of my slide, the sentence "The mean of the Gaussian distribution is well estimated whenever $n \geq 30$" (is wrong and) has nothing to do here.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent to generate the animation I used ImageMagick and `convert -density 300 -delay 100 test.pdf test.gif` . I then inserted the resulting `.gif` animation using the button above the answer window.

Comment: looks nice. Do you know, how to get the two subitems below the alertbox to correct indentation? (They should be one itemize indent further right)